# Creating a page look in the centre of a page

Tags: html, css

I am looking for the page look; when there is a (what looks like) frame in the centre and an image around that or a blank background. http://hopelessrecords.com/about-us/ this is a link to a site, the page and background idea is what I would like to achieve.

(I didn't know how to phrase this properly so forgive me if my terminology is off and there is something out there that I missed when searching).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it in css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(./yourImage.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.yourPage {
    max-width: 1230px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

And this in html

```
<div class="yourPage">
    Your content
</div>
```

```css
html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .yourPage {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="yourPage">
    Your content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below to your styles.css

```
body { padding: 5em 15em; /* adds a spacing of 5x the font size to the top and bottom, and 15x of that to the left and right sides of the page. */
```

Read  [for a complete guide on padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp), or check [MDN article on box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)